# Hibernate JPA, Problems adding data to a many to many table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am creating a database and am having trouble getting the data to add to the many to many table connecting the operators to the routes they operate. All other data adds fine and I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.

Here's an extract from the console return, it shows that the operates table, the one I am failing to add too, has a different message

```
Hibernate: 
alter table operates 
    add index FKE22A276FF12BFD7F (number), 
    add constraint FKE22A276FF12BFD7F 
    foreign key (number) 
    references route (number)
Hibernate: 
alter table operates 
    add index FKE22A276FC0CF67CB (name), 
    add constraint FKE22A276FC0CF67CB 
    foreign key (name) 
    references operator (name)
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    bus_stop
    (description, id) 
values
    (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    bus_stop
    (description, id) 
values
    (?, ?)
```

Here's some of my code, have left out the get and set methods since they will be fine:

Route

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Route.SELECT_ALL, query = "select r from Route r 
order by r.number asc")
})
@Table(name = "route")
public class Route {
    @Id  @Column(name="number")
    private String number;

    private int frequency;
    private String start;
private String destination;

@ManyToMany(
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
        mappedBy = "routes",
        targetEntity = Operator.class)
private Set<Operator> operators = new HashSet<Operator>();
```

Operator

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Operator.SELECT_ALL, query = "select o from Operator 
 o order by o.name asc")
 })
 @Table(name = "operator")
 public class Operator {

@Id  @Column(name="name")
private String name;

private String street;
private String town;
private String postcode;
private String email;
private String phone;

@ManyToMany(
        targetEntity=Route.class,
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="operates",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="name"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="number")
    )
private Set<Route> routes;
```

and the respective insert statements

```
    public static Session insert(final Map<String, String> row, Session session) {
    Operator o = new Operator();
    o.setRoutes(new HashSet<Route>());

    for (String key : row.keySet()) {
        if(key.equals("name"))
            o.setName(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("street"))
            o.setStreet(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("town"))
            o.setTown(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("postcode"))
            o.setPostcode(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("email"))
            o.setEmail(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("phone"))
            o.setPhone(row.get(key));
    }
    session.save(o);

    return session; 

public static Session insert(final Map<String, String> row, final Session session) {

        Route r = new Route();
        r.setOperators(new HashSet<Operator>());

        for (String key : row.keySet()) {
            if(key.equals("number"))
                r.setNumber(row.get(key));
            else if(key.equals("frequency"))
                r.setFrequency(Integer.parseInt(row.get(key)));
            else if(key.equals("start"))
                r.setStart(row.get(key));
            else if(key.equals("destination"))
                    r.setDestination(row.get(key));
            else if(key.equals("operators")){
                Set<String> operatorStrings = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(row.get(key).split("|")));

                Operator o = new Operator();
                for(String s : operatorStrings){
                    o.setName(s);
                    r.getOperators().add(o);
                }
            }
        }

        session.save(r);

        return session;
    }
```

extra for comment

```
    Route r = new Route();
    r.setOperators(new HashSet<Operator>());

    for (String key : row.keySet()) {
        if(key.equals("number"))
            r.setNumber(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("frequency"))
            r.setFrequency(Integer.parseInt(row.get(key)));
        else if(key.equals("start"))
            r.setStart(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("destination"))
                r.setDestination(row.get(key));
        else if(key.equals("operators")){
            Set<String> operatorStrings = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(row.get(key).split("|")));


            Operator o = new Operator();
            for(String s : operatorStrings){                    
                o.setName(s);
                o.setRoutes(new HashSet<Route>());
                o.getRoutes().add(r);
                r.getOperators().add(o);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any `operator.setRoute()`, or `operator.getRoutes().add()` method call in what you posted. That's what is missing.

Comment: Ok I left out a little detail in my question, we are provided with csv files for the tables. For the routes table there is a provided column for operators operating that route, however this is not the case for the operator csv with routes. So how and where would I add this?

Comment: Every time you add an operator to a route, make sure to also add the route to the operator.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty new to this stuff, I still don't quite understand, I get the concept but can't wrap my head around implementing it, so when I do the line r.getOperators().add(o) I should have a line adding r to o just before?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Ok so I have tried what I think you mean and still the same problem, I'll update my post to show what I changed as an extra note at the bottom, sorry for being a nuisance but this is really stressing me out so I want to fix it, I appreciate the help

Comment: Is it possible that I need to switch around the many to many declaration so it's the other way around, if that makes sense.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You're creating a single Operator instance, and settings its name and routes in a loop. You're also never persisting that operator.

Comment: Yeah I keep going round in circles and I'm making my code worse and worse slowly, since I have been given a long string with multiple operator names which I need to parse and then add to the many to many relationship table to show that the operate the given route I thought this would be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When adding Oerator or Route make sure that `Route` is in `Operators.routes` collection and operator is in `Route.operators`

In Route do:

```
public void addOperator(Operator o){
operators.add(o);
o.addRoute(this);
}
```

In Operator do:

```
public void addRoute(Route r){
routes.add(r);
r.addOperator(this);
}
```

And the same do when removing route or operator. This ensures that both sides of many-to-many relation are in sync.

Comment: I have tried but can't get it to work still, thanks for the answer though. What you are saying makes perfect sense but I can't figure out how to implement it properly. So basically I have two csv files. The route file has the names of the operators that run that route but the operator file does not the list of routes each operator runs. So perhaps I am going about it the wrong way? Any further help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many

Comment: Thanks jay, looks helpful. Aprreciated!

Comment: Thank you have finally sorted my issue, your answer helped me figure out the issue although it took a little more digging as well. As said before greatly appreciated, you've saved me lots of stress.